# Openconnect certificate validation with NetworkManager

Tags: vpn, ssl, certificate, networkmanager

On my Cinnamon (linux) desktop, I have setup an openconnect VPN connection in NetworkManager. When connecting, I don't seem to have any issues: the connection is established and network traffic is routed through it. However, my system log contains a worrying entry:

```
openconnect[2935]: SSL negotiation with (...)
openconnect[2935]: Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
openconnect[2935]: Connected to HTTPS on (...)
openconnect[2935]: Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I tried using `openconnect` from the command line and it does not print anything about certificate issues (even in verbose mode). Also, there are no certificate errors with the site in Firefox or using `wget` (I have no idea which certificate store openconnect uses...).

Does that mean that the connection is prone to man-in-the-middle attacks? If the certificate could not be verified, why is there no confirmation prompt which asks me to trust the certificate before connecting and sending my credentials? Why is the issue only present when connecting using NetworkManager?

The command line of `openconnect` is

```
/usr/sbin/openconnect --servercert sha1:bee140657db50a73ee69f47fee9e4d670905206e --syslog --cookie-on-stdin --script /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openconnect-service-openconnect-helper --interface vpn0 (ip):443
```

The warning is also present if I do not explicitly set a CA certificate in NetworkManager.

Comment: Use `ps aux | grep openconnect` to check if there are any command line options being passed to it by NetworkManager.

Comment: @garethTheRed: I added the result to the question. As soon as I figure out how to reset the CA certificate (which seems to be impossible using the GUI), I can also post the command line for that configuration.

Comment: The command line is the same if I do not specify a CA certificate. I have no idea where it gets the `--servercert` from.

Comment: A quick glance at the source code shows that the `--servercert` verb is added by `nm-openconnect-service.c`.  I attempted (not very successfully) to follow the code and from my understanding it seems like `--servercert` refers to the hash of the certificate of the remote server, presumably stored from a previous connection. `man openconnect` also mentions the same.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is still present in Ubuntu 18.04 with `network-manager-openconnect`.

I think the issue here is that the connection is being made to the VPN server's IP address, rather than it's DNS name:

```
$ ps aux | grep openconnect
/usr/sbin/openconnect --servercert sha256:<hash> --syslog --cookie-on-stdin --script /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openconnect-service-openconnect-helper --interface vpn0 <ip>:443
```

Run the command manually, without the --servercert parameter:

```
$ /usr/sbin/openconnect <ip>:443 --authenticate
POST https://<ip>/
Connected to <ip>:443
SSL negotiation with <ip>
Server certificate verify failed: certificate does not match hostname
Certificate from VPN server "<ip>" failed verification.
Reason: certificate does not match hostname
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
   --servercert sha256:<hash>
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view:
```

Note the certificate verification failure.

Now using the hostname instead of the IP:

```
$ /usr/sbin/openconnect <hostname>:443 --authenticate
POST https://<hostname>/
Connected to <ip>:443
SSL negotiation with <hostname>
Connected to HTTPS on <hostname>
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
```

No certificate errors.

Now, using the IP with the servercert parameter:

```
$ /usr/sbin/openconnect <ip>:443 --authenticate --servercert sha256:<hash>
POST https://<ip>/
Connected to <ip>:443
SSL negotiation with <ip>
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on <ip>
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
```

Compare the error to the first example - it's a different error. This one fails because the signer is not found. Considering that we're just specifying a hash, I guess that makes sense, as there's not trust chain to follow.

To me, I think the root cause is that network manager is for some reason connecting to the IP address rather than the hostname. Not sure why it would do this?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. This could quite well be the cause of the issue (although it doesn't really provide a solution). Unfortunately, I cannot test this myself since the VPN service I was having problems with does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue in Arch Linux using networkmanager-connect and the network-manager-applet. I solved this by manually downloading the ca certificate:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect <HOST>:<PORTNUMBER> \
| sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ~/vpn.crt
```

[[source]](https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website)

And then I selected that file in the VPN configuration menu in Gnome's Network Settings. This adds the following line to configuration file /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyVpn.nmconnection:

```
[vpn]
...
cacert=/home/<my username>/vpn.crt
```

It might change some other lines in the config file. I didn't run a diff to find out. But in any case, I was then enable to connect to my vpn through Network Manager.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. The config file already contains a valid path to the certificate and I have never had any issues with actually connecting, just a security warning.

Comment: This answer is maybe not the expected answer to the OP's question, but it's exactly what I was looking for (using it I don't need to acknowledge the certificate warning each time I connect to my VPN). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @curvy stated, the network-manager-openconnect uses the ip address instead of the hostname. This is a problem with vpn gateways that provide hostname-only certificates.

To avoid this problem, you can recompile https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openconnect applying this simple patch.

```
diff --git a/src/nm-openconnect-service.c b/src/nm-openconnect-service.c
index 348c19a..273efb5 100644
--- a/src/nm-openconnect-service.c
+++ b/src/nm-openconnect-service.c
@@ -415,9 +415,10 @@ nm_openconnect_start_openconnect_binary (NMOpenconnectPlugin *plugin,
        return -1;
    }
 
-   /* The actual gateway to use (after redirection) comes from the auth
-      dialog, so it's in the secrets hash not the properties */
-   props_vpn_gw = nm_setting_vpn_get_secret (s_vpn, NM_OPENCONNECT_KEY_GATEWAY);
+   /* Replaced nm_setting_vpn_get_secret with nm_setting_vpn_get_data_item
+      because if we use ip to get connection we may have problems with
+        certificates signed only with hostnames */
+   props_vpn_gw = nm_setting_vpn_get_data_item (s_vpn, NM_OPENCONNECT_KEY_GATEWAY);
    if (!props_vpn_gw || !strlen (props_vpn_gw) ) {
        g_set_error (error,
                     NM_VPN_PLUGIN_ERROR,
@@ -596,7 +597,7 @@ real_need_secrets (NMVpnServicePlugin *plugin,
    }
 
    /* We just need the WebVPN cookie, and the final IP address of the gateway
-      (after HTTP redirects, which do happen). All the certificate/SecurID 
+      (after HTTP redirects, which do happen). All the certificate/SecurID
       nonsense can be handled for us, in the user's context, by auth-dialog */
    if (!nm_setting_vpn_get_secret (s_vpn, NM_OPENCONNECT_KEY_GATEWAY)) {
        *setting_name = NM_SETTING_VPN_SETTING_NAME;
```